# Symfony how to get if preRemove listener is triggered by remove or by orphanRemoval=true

Tags: php, symfony, orm

In Symfony, when working with Doctrine ORM, you may encounter a situation where you need to determine whether a preRemove listener is triggered as a result of a regular entity removal or because of the orphanRemoval=true option. This scenario typically arises when dealing with related entities and their cascading removal.

I have categories and products.
I want on preRemove categories to add a message to users for each product that they have in their cart
But in preRemove listener, all products are detached already.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: How i solved my problem, I removed orphanRemoval from my orm file. as i haven't found any solutions... I added in preRemove listener to delete all childs manually